# How to translate "News Junkie" to Spanish?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos

Does anyone know what would be the right translation of the term "news junkie" to Spanish?

Or a term which better fits as most used translation for it?

Answer (score 4):

"*Noticiadicto*" doesn't exist in Spanish. To use an accepted expression in correct Spanish that conveys the meaning of "*news junkie*", would be better to use "***adicta/o a las noticias***".

Answer (score 2):

Based on the same construction as *drogadicto* (*drug addict*) you could use the invented *noticiadicto* (*noticias* + *adicto*).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, 
however I would like to know if there is already a term which is already popular, before I can use the invented "noticiadicto"? Anyone??

Muchas gracias! 
De todas formas, alguien sabe si ya existe alguna traducción que se use y esté establecida, antes de usar el invento: "noticiadicto"?

Answer (score 1):

Adicto a las noticias o adicta a las noticias es lo que más se acerca. Los términos coloquiales de drogadicto no se han utilizado hasta el momento para describir una gran afición a algo. Adicto al fútbol, Adicto a facebook son otros ejemplos. Algunos equivalentes para junkie son: marihuano, drogo, moto, monero, motorolo.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarifying, *adicto* it's a formal way for medical and psycology usage, and that would be a News-addict

But this is not the case, Junkie it's like an slang, so if you want something more informal you could use: *Traumado por las noticias*, at least in México, maybe in other countries the word *Traumado* could be replaced.